# Works in iPhone Simulator, but not on Phone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have an app which runs fine on the simulator, but not on the actual device.

At runtime, it gives me the following error:

```
2010-12-05 19:58:32.006 Sports[4668:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x800800'
```

A bit about the structure: I have a Tab Bar Controller, the first view being a UINavigationController.

The view in there is a UITableView. One thing that may or may not be related is that if I do @synthesize tableView; in the table view controller, the table stays blank on both simulator and phone (but does not crash).

If I take that out, it loads the correct data on the simulator, and crashes on the phone.

Where should delegate/dataSource be linked to in the Interface Builder? I tried linking it to "View" to "File's Owner", and making a new "ViewController" and none of those worked.

Comment: Also, I'm rather confused as to where [UITableView isEqualToString:] is even called.

Answer (score 2):

Both the `delegate` and `dataSource` should be linked to `File's Owner`, which is the view controller class that declares the table view as an `IBOutlet`; this should be the same view controller that owns the nib file. Additionally, that view controller should be implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

Add that `@synthesize` line back in, (unless you're subclassing `UITableViewController`, as pointed out by grahamparks in the comments!) make sure those connections are right, and, finally, make sure you've declared an `IBOutlet` for the table view, and connected that properly between your class and interface builder.

Comment: Yep, delegate and dataSource are linked to File's Owner. There is an IBOutlet for the table view, called tableView. I don't see where to link that in interface builder though. There's an outlet called "view" that I connected to File's Owner. There's my tableView under FirstViewController, but hooking that up to the table view doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: You'll have to declare an outlet for your tableView in your view controller header, with `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`. Then, you should see that connection show up in interface builder. Does that work out?

Comment: If the view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController (and it sounds like it is), then it has its own built-in tableView property that you normally shouldn't override. Hence, leave out the synthesize directive.

Comment: it's declared, and it shows up in interface builder under First View Controller. Where does that go though?

Comment: @graham, yes, it is a subclass of UITableViewController. Leaving out synthesize causes it to crash when run on iPhone with the error I said above.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Turns out that there wasn't really a problem with this at all. The problem was that the date field in my database, when run on my phone was always zero/nil.

Why? Because the NSDate object created never initialized and stayed at nil.

Why?

Because my phone is in 24 hour time and did not parse the am and pm properly.

Lessons learned!

Answer (score 0):

Run your app with NSZombieEnabled set to yes. See http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled for an explanation about it and how to set it. I think what you will find is that the app will now throw an exception in the simulator telling you that you are sending a message to an object that has been released.

Based on the error message you are receiving, I expect the culprit is a NSString or NSMutableString object. If it is an NSString then warning, that NSString could be shared by several different objects so figuring out where the extra release is might be hard.

Never fear though, Instruments helps tremendously in this regard. Here is a link that explains how to use Instruments to find out exactly where your object is being retained and released so you can track down which release is inappropriate. http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Good luck!